# Converting a postive integer to a negative

Tags: ruby

I am new to programming and was curious to know why the following returns a negative integer:

```
-num.abs
```

My understanding is that abs returns the value as a positive number yet this will return any positive number into a negative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why the following returns a negative integer: `-num.abs`

Because it's `-(num.abs)`, not `(-num).abs`. First, you take `abs`, then you negate that value, resulting in a negative number.